# To prove f(0) = 0 and hence f is a bijection

Tags: complex-analysis

let $ f:\mathbf{D}\rightarrow \mathbf{D}$ be a holomorphic function. And suppose that it is **Bijective on ${D}\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}\rightarrow \mathbf{D}\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \} $**. Can we conclude that
f(0) = 0?

I can conclude that  $\begin{vmatrix}f(0)\end{vmatrix} < 1$ because other wise if  $\begin{vmatrix}f(0)\end{vmatrix} = 1$ then by maximum modulus principle f(z) is constant but that cannot happen because the function is a bijection. but from this is it possible to deduce that f(0)=0 ?

I'm referring the correct answer of [conformal self maps on punctured disk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265396/how-to-prove-conformal-self-map-of-punctured-disk-0z1-is-rotation)

Comment: If $f(0)\neq 0$, then $f(z)=a$ would have precisely two solutions for precisely one value of $a$. I feel like [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) should show this is a contradiction, but it might be a bit of an overkill.

Comment: Intuitively, I'm pretty sure continuity should be enough to prove this.

Comment: Hi. Check the link I posted on the content. It said  once by images of points z near 0 and once by images of points... can you please elaborate it

Comment: It's bijective on $D\setminus\{0\}$, and $f(0)\not 0$ implies $f(0)\in D\setminus\{0\}$. So $f(0)$ has a preimage in $D\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(0) = a$ with $0<|a|<1.$ As $f:\mathbb D /\{0\} \mapsto \mathbb D /\{0\} ,$ So there exist a point $b\in \mathbb D /\{0\}$ so that $f(b)= a.$ Consider the function $g: \mathbb D \mapsto \mathbb D$ defined by $g(z)= f(z)- a.$ The function $g$ has a zero at $b$ and $0.$ Let order of the zero of $g$ at $b$ and $0$ be $m_1, m_2$ respectively. Note that $m_1,m_2 \geq 1.$

So there exist $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 >0$ and a $\delta>0$ so that each point $w$ in $B(0,\delta),$  the equation $g(z)=w$ has exactly $m_1$ simple root in $B(b,\epsilon_1)$ and $m_2$ simple root in $B(o,\epsilon_2).$ Note that $\delta$ can be taken so small so that corresponding $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ will have the property that $B(o,\epsilon_2) \cap B(b,\epsilon_1) = \emptyset. $ In that case bijectivity of $f$ in $\mathbb D/\{0\}$ will be contradicted.

Hence $f(0)$ must be $0.$

Comment: Yes Agree with you :)

Comment: I detected a typo in here @timon.. the last equation should be non empty

Comment: @ charith, actually I need,  ball in domain side should be disjoint so that I can say each point in range has at least two preimage which is a contradiction for the injectivity of f.

Comment: Ah Yes. You are correct. Thankz @timon

Answer (score 0):

I'm Referring the book [Function Theory of One Complex Variable
By Robert Everist Greene, Steven George Krantz.](http://bookzz.org/s/?q=Function+Theory+of+One+Complex+Variable+By+Robert+Everist+Greene%2C+Steven+George+Krantz.&yearFrom=&yearTo=&language=&extension=&t=0).

Supppose that

$f(0) \neq 0 $ then  $ \exists z` \in  \mathbb{D} \setminus  \begin{Bmatrix}0\end{Bmatrix}  $ such that $f(0) = z`$. Also note that  $ \exists z_{1} \in  \mathbb{D} \setminus  \begin{Bmatrix}0\end{Bmatrix}  $ such that $f(z_{1}) = z`$.

Now by using [Theorem 5.2.2](https://books.google.lk/books?id=u5vhseYCcqkC&pg=PA164&dq=theorem%205.2.2%20Robert%20E%20greene%20and%20steven&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=theorem%205.2.2%20Robert%20E%20greene%20and%20steven&f=false) we have $ \delta_{0},  \varepsilon _{0}, \delta_{1},  \varepsilon _{1} $ such that $ \forall z \in D(z`,\varepsilon _{0}) \setminus \{z` \}  $ has exactly one pre image on $ D(0,\delta_{0}) $.

and similarly $ \forall z \in D(z`,\varepsilon _{1}) \setminus \{z` \}  $ has exactly one pre image on $ D(0,\delta_{1}) $.

now by considering the intersection of two open balls $D(z`,\varepsilon _{0}) \setminus \{z` \}$ and $D(z`,\varepsilon _{1}) \setminus \{z` \}$ which is nonempty we can contradict with the fact that the function is one to one on the punctured disc.